# Security namespace does not support decoration of element [custom-filter]

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I need to perform custom authorization, so I've predetermined `AuthenticationManager` and `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint` and set it into `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`.

Here is my `spring-security.xml`:

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <security:http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="alterAuthenticationEntryPoint" create-session="always" use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/blog**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="d" password="secret" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <security:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="customizedFormLoginFilter"/><!--replace the default one-->

    <bean id="customizedFormLoginFilter"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager"
                  ref="alterAuthenticationManager"/>
        <property name="allowSessionCreation" value="true"/> 
    </bean>

    <!--Custom auth manager-->
    <bean id="alterAuthenticationManager" class="com.fluid.ixtrm.newmodule.security.CustomAuthenticationManager"/>

    <!--Authentication entry point-->
    <bean id="alterAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="com.fluid.ixtrm.newmodule.security.CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="/blog"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Both classes (`CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint extends LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint` and `CustomAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager`) are implemented, but it would be too much code samples (I don't think that they cause the problem).

I'm getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Security namespace does not support decoration of element [custom-filter]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]
```

I use Spring Security 3.2.3, and `custom-filter` tag is present in `spring-security-3.2.xsd`. Tell me please what is incorrect in my security config.

Comment: that needs to go inside the `security:http` element not as a root element,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your configuration is not valid, see [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-custom-filter):

> **41.1.19 <custom-filter>**
>
> This element is used to add a filter to the filter chain. It doesn’t create any additional beans but is used to select a bean of type `javax.servlet.Filter` which is already defined in the application context and add that at a particular position in the filter chain maintained by Spring Security. Full details can be found in the namespace chapter.
>
> **Parent Elements of <custom-filter>**
>
> - http

Your modified configuration of `<security:http>`:

```xml
<security:http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="alterAuthenticationEntryPoint" create-session="always" use-expressions="true">
   <security:intercept-url pattern="/blog**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
   <security:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="customizedFormLoginFilter"/>
</security:http>
```